# TFTPy import, no module named tftpy

Tags: python, pip, python-import, importerror

I installed TFTPy with both pip and pip3.
Then i followed the example on the TFTPy documentation, which follows:

```py
import tftpy

server = tftpy.TftpServer('/tftpboot')
server.listen('0.0.0.0', 69)
```

But I get the error

> ImportError: No module named tftpy

I also tried using `from tftpy import tftpy`. I tried using Python 2, Python 2.7 and Python 3, but still get the same error.

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can install `tftpy` by using command `pip install tftpy`. In case you do not have pip on your device, use the following commands:

```
yum -y install python-pip
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tftpy
```